# How to speed up sql creating process

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

in my app, i create rows to sql table.

```
int findNewId = Entities.myTable.Where(a => a.Name == txtName.Text).Select(b => b.Id).FirstOrDefault();

for (int i = 0; i < incomingDtbl.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    addNew.Id = findNewId;
    addNew.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(incomingDtbl.Rows[i].ItemArray[2]);
    addNew.Hour = Convert.ToInt32(incomingDtbl.Rows[i].ItemArray[3]);
    ...
    addNew.CreationDate = System.DateTime.Now;
    Entities.myTable.Add(addNew);
    Entities.SaveChanges();

}
```

but my incomingDtbl has like 130000 rows, so it takes soooo long.
is there any way to speed this process up?

i cant directly bulk copy the incomingDtbl because it doesnt have newId.

Comment: Does `Entities.SaveChanges();`  persist the changes to the database? If so; you can try calling it only after every few 100 rows instead after every single row

Comment: `because it doesnt have newId` in general, consider letting your database decide on new technical keys, instead of your software. Databases are pretty good at it, and it saves you quite a lot of hassle.

Comment: @oerkelens my destination tbl has  columns like: logId, newId, date, hour.... so i need newId.

Comment: You can temporary disable `validation` and `ChangeTracking`. and also take out `Entities.SaveChanges();` out of loop. It will improve performance. 
`Entities.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` and `Entities.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;`

Comment: like this? @AmitKumar

for (int i = 0; i < incomingDtbl.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    addNew.Id = findNewId;
    addNew.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(incomingDtbl.Rows[i].ItemArray[2]);
    addNew.Hour = Convert.ToInt32(incomingDtbl.Rows[i].ItemArray[3]);
    ...
    addNew.CreationDate = System.DateTime.Now;
    Entities.myTable.Add(addNew);


}
Entities.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true; and Entities.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
Entities.SaveChanges();

Comment: Yes. but `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` should be false.  `Entities.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false; `  and also instead of making each request to get id, get it in single query and keep it in memory.

Comment: @AmitKumar when i take out the SaveChanges(); out of loop, it only save the last row. :/

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem as well (Mine were 170,000 rows). Here's my solution:

```cs
    public bool InsertData(List<MachineInfo> MachineInfo, string flag,int userID)
    {
        if (MachineInfo != null && flag != string.Empty)
        {
            List<T> attList = new List<T>();
            foreach (var item in MachineInfo)
            {
                T att = new T()
                {
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                    DateTime = item.DateTimeRecord,
                    EnrollNumber = item.EnrollNumber.ToString(),
                    IPFlag = flag,
                    SyncBy = userID
                };
                attList.Add(att);
            }
            try
            {
                Entities context = null;
                try
                {
                    context = new Entities();
                    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

                    int count = 0;
                    foreach (var entity in attList)
                    {
                        ++count;
                        context = AddToContext(context, entity, count, 100, true);
                    }

                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (context != null)
                        context.Dispose();
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

```cs
    private Entities AddToContext(Entities context, T entity, int count, int commitCount, bool recreateContext)
    {
        context.Set<T>().Add(entity);

        if (count % commitCount == 0)
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
            if (recreateContext)
            {
                context.Dispose();
                context = new Entities();
                context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            }
        }

        return context;
    }
```

It performs really fast because it splits the records and also help you validate.

All the best!!!